# Why uwsgi return empty when curl?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask Uwsgi deploy

It was working fine until today

Curl to the server will get below

```
curl http://ip:5000/api -i
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

**The uwsgi log shows below** （Please do not say check logs any more. Logs are here already）

```
[pid: 15778|app: 0|req: 552000/854000] 8.8.8.8 () {22 vars in 241 bytes} [Wed May 30 16:40:51 2018] HEAD / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.0 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
...The work of process 15778 is done. Seeya!
worker 1 killed successfully (pid: 15778)
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 18478
```

**Also this one is not duplicate to the question** [Django, uWSGI & nginx: Process dies for "no reason"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430370/django-uwsgi-nginx-process-dies-for-no-reason)

The cause for that one is that he has a setting

```
--max-requests 10
```

And he do not have the Master setting. So in his log you can see req 1000/1000 which reach the limit. Mine is not!!!

I set the master=true in my conf also you can see from the wsgi log. not reaching the max request!!!

The config of uwsgi is like below

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/var/tmp/uwsgi.sock
http= 0.0.0.0:5000
chdir=/opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server
wsgi-file = app.py
callable=app
master = true
processes=2
threads=2
max-requests=2000
chmod-socket=664
vacuum=true
daemonize = /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/var/log/uwsgi.log
```

I can see the process still  there and the 5000 port being listened

```
ps -ef | grep wsgi| grep -v grep| grep -v tail
root      2083 22075  0 May28 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi --ini /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/conf/wsgi.ini
root     18478 22075  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 uwsgi --ini /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/conf/wsgi.ini
root     22075     1  0 May24 ?        00:02:50 uwsgi --ini /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/conf/wsgi.ini
root     22090 22075  0 May24 ?        00:01:48 uwsgi --ini /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/conf/wsgi.ini
```

Although it is worth noticing that only two process listening 5000 and uwsgi have 4 process

```
lsof -i:5000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
uwsgi   22075 root    3u  IPv4 76455578      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
uwsgi   22090 root    3u  IPv4 76455578      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

So what is happening to uwsig and how to check?

Comment: First at all check logs: /opt/CephMGRServer/ceph_mgr_server/var/log/uwsgi.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, uWSGI & nginx: Process dies for "no reason"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430370/django-uwsgi-nginx-process-dies-for-no-reason)

Comment: @gbajson  The  log  information already included in the question.

Comment: @Fian NO. I see that question. The issue for that one is req 1000/1000 which reach the limit. This one is not

Comment: Any update on this? Facing similar kind of issue.

Comment: This is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can not query it directly.
You should configure upstream in NGINX config and point to your uwsgi unix/tcp socket

Or just run uwsgi with http/https socket

Smth like this uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --httpsocket 80 (can't recall correct option)